# Scanner Brother dcp-1510 - Sane?

Tags: printing, scanner

Hi i have a combined printer / scanner Brother hl 2030 which i have connected to a ubuntu 18.04 through usb i can see the printer and it work but have tried to scan in a scan program and it says there is no scanner on the system.

How do I make the scanner work?

Should I use sane?